# Find the orthogonal complement $W^{\bot}$ of W and give a basis for $W^{\bot}$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I have no clue how to start solving this. I've been watching videos and looking at examples but I can't find any. I couldn't find an example in my textbook either.

$$W=
        \begin{Bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        x\\
        y\\
        z\\
        \end{bmatrix}: 2x-y+z=0
        \end{Bmatrix}
$$

Can I get a few hints on how to go about this?

Comment: One way is to first find a basis of $W$, let's say $W=Span(e_1,e_2)$ and then check that $u=(x,y,z)\in W^\perp$ iff the scalar product $u\cdot e_1=u\cdot e_2=0$. This gives you linear equations describing $W^\perp$. You could also notice that $W$ is actually the orthogonal complement of a one dimensional subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
$$W= \{ (x,y,z)^T : (2, -1, 1) \cdot (x,y,z)^T = 0\}$$
where $\cdot$ denotes the scalar product. So $W$ is exactly the orthogonal of the 1-dimensional space spanned by $(2, -1, 1)$.

Now, what can we say about the orthogonal of $W$?